# How to split a string into efficient way c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
 -82.9494547,36.2913021,0
 -83.0784938,36.2347521,0
 -82.9537782,36.079235,0
```

I need to have output like this:

```
 -82.9494547 36.2913021, -83.0784938 36.2347521, -82.9537782,36.079235
```

I have tried this following to code to achieve the desired output:

```
string[] coordinatesVal = coordinateTxt.Trim().Split(new string[] { ",0" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesVal.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            coordinatesVal[i] = coordinatesVal[i].Trim();
            coordinatesVal[i] = coordinatesVal[i].Replace(',', ' ');

            numbers.Append(coordinatesVal[i]);

            if (i != coordinatesVal.Length - 1)
            {
                coordinatesVal.Append(", ");
            }

        }
```

But this process does not seem to me the professional solution. Can anyone please suggest more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Your solution is okay. You could chain `Trim` and `Replace`: `coordinatesVal[i] = coordinatesVal[i].Trim().Replace(',', ' ');`. Also, you could always append `", "` and after the loop correct the length of the `StringBuilder` with `coordinatesVal.Length -= 2;`

Comment: thanks for reply. But is it possible to do it with less lines of code?

Comment: It would appear you see "the professional solution", "more efficient" and "less lines of code" as synonims. They are not, and often are quite the opposite.

Comment: It can be done with one line of code if you remove the line end characters.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius how to do that?

Comment: Does string include newline after ",0" as displayed in a sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is okay. You could dismiss temporary results and chain method calls

```
var numbers = new StringBuilder();
string[] coordinatesVal = coordinateTxt
    .Trim()
    .Split(new string[] { ",0" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesVal.Length - 1; i++) {
    numbers
        .Append(coordinatesVal[i].Trim().Replace(',', ' '))
        .Append(", ");
}
numbers.Length -= 2;
```

Note that the last statement assumes that there is at least one coordinate pair available. If the coordinates can be empty, you would have to enclose the loop and this last statement in `if (coordinatesVal.Length > 0 ) { ... }`. This is still more efficient than having an `if` inside the loop.

Comment: There is a bug (in the OP code too). Imagine this input: -82.9494547,0.2913021,0

Comment: @AntonínLejsek i thought about that scenario after i made my post. all solutions here except harun would fail in that scenario. after several optimal attempts considering that scenario, i could not beat harun's time. if that scenario is possible or if the third value might not be 0, harun solution is the way to go hands down. which is why i upvoted his solution. However, it is possible that the data will never contain a leading zero and it will always contain a trailing 0. in that case my second method would be fastest unless the data is rather large then harun again would be the way to go.

Comment: A safer approach would be to split twice. First split into lines, then split each line into 3 parts at the commas.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about efficiency, but you don't specify whether you mean code efficiency (execution speed) or programmer efficiency (how much time you have to spend on it).
One key part of professional programming is to judge which one of these is more important in any given situation.

The other answers do an excellent job of covering programmer efficiency, so I'm taking a stab at code efficiency. I'm doing this at home for fun, but for professional work, I would need a good reason before putting in the effort to even spend time comparing the speeds of the methods given in the other answers, let alone trying to improve on them.

Waiting around for the program to finish doing the conversion of millions of coordinate pairs would give me such a reason.

One of the speed pitfalls of C# string handling is the way `String.Replace()` and `String.Trim()` return a whole new copy of the string. This involves allocating memory, copying the characters, and eventually cleaning up the garbage generated. Do that a few million times, and it starts to add up. With that in mind, I attempted to avoid as many allocations and copies as possible.

```
    enum CurrentField
    {
        FirstNum,
        SecondNum,
        UnwantedZero
    };

    static string ConvertStateMachine(string input)
    {
        // Pre-allocate enough space in the string builder.
        var numbers = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

        var state = CurrentField.FirstNum;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < input.Length)
        {
            char c = input[i++];

            switch (state)
            {
                // Copying the first number to the output, next will be another number
                case CurrentField.FirstNum:
                    if (c == ',')
                    {
                        // Separate the two numbers by space instead of comma, then move on
                        numbers.Append(' ');
                        state = CurrentField.SecondNum;
                    }
                    else if (!(c == ' ' || c == '\n'))
                    {
                        // Ignore whitespace, output anything else
                        numbers.Append(c);
                    }
                    break;

                // Copying the second number to the output, next will be the ,0\n that we don't need
                case CurrentField.SecondNum:
                    if (c == ',')
                    {
                        numbers.Append(", ");
                        state = CurrentField.UnwantedZero;
                    }
                    else if (!(c == ' ' || c == '\n'))
                    {
                        // Ignore whitespace, output anything else
                        numbers.Append(c);
                    }
                    break;
                case CurrentField.UnwantedZero:
                    // Output nothing, just track when the line is finished and we start all over again.
                    if (c == '\n')
                    {
                        state = CurrentField.FirstNum;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return numbers.ToString();
    }
```

This uses a state machine to treat incoming characters differently depending on whether they are part of the first number, second number, or the rest of the line, and output characters accordingly. Each character is only copied once into the output, then I believe once more when the output is converted to a string at the end. This second conversion could probably be avoided by using a `char[]` for the output.

The bottleneck in this code seems to be the number of calls to `StringBuilder.Append()`. If more speed were required, I would first attempt to keep track of how many characters would be copied directly into the output, then use `.Append(string value, int startIndex, int count)` to send an entire number across in one call.

I put a few example solutions into a test harness, and ran them on a string containing 300,000 coordinate-pair lines, averaged over 50 runs.  The results on my PC were:

```
String Split, Replace each line (see Olivier's answer, though I pre-allocated the space in the StringBuilder):
    6542 ms / 13493147 ticks, 130.84ms / 269862.9 ticks per conversion
Replace & Trim the entire string (see Heriberto's second version):
    3352 ms / 6914604 ticks, 67.04 ms / 138292.1 ticks per conversion
    - Note: Original test was done with 900000 coord pairs, but this entire-string version suffered an out-of-memory exception so I had to rein it in a bit.
Split and Join (see Łukasz's answer):
    8780 ms / 18110672 ticks, 175.6 ms / 362213.4 ticks per conversion
The character state machine (see above):
    1685 ms / 3475506 ticks, 33.7 ms / 69510.12 ticks per conversion
```

So, the question of which version is most efficient comes down to: what are your requirements?

**UPDATE:** 24 June 2023

Placing benchmarks for different split methods using BenchmarkDotNet

```
|                                Method |  Size |           Mean |        Error |       StdDev |       StdErr |            Min |             Q1 |         Median |             Q3 |            Max |        Op/s | Ratio |      Gen0 |      Gen1 |     Gen2 |  Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
|-------------------------------------- |------ |---------------:|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|---------------:|---------------:|---------------:|---------------:|---------------:|------------:|------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|-----------:|------------:|
|                    ConvertReplaceTrim |     1 |       143.0 ns |      0.21 ns |      0.17 ns |      0.05 ns |       142.7 ns |       142.9 ns |       143.0 ns |       143.1 ns |       143.3 ns | 6,992,805.0 |  0.50 |    0.1121 |         - |        - |      704 B |        0.58 |
|                   ConvertStateMachine |     1 |       154.7 ns |      0.23 ns |      0.22 ns |      0.06 ns |       154.4 ns |       154.6 ns |       154.7 ns |       154.9 ns |       155.2 ns | 6,462,059.3 |  0.54 |    0.0625 |         - |        - |      392 B |        0.32 |
| ConvertStateMachineValueStringBuilder |     1 |       177.8 ns |      0.28 ns |      0.25 ns |      0.07 ns |       177.4 ns |       177.6 ns |       177.8 ns |       178.0 ns |       178.1 ns | 5,624,207.7 |  0.63 |    0.0267 |         - |        - |      168 B |        0.14 |
|                    ConvertStringSplit |     1 |       284.5 ns |      0.74 ns |      0.69 ns |      0.18 ns |       282.9 ns |       284.1 ns |       284.5 ns |       284.9 ns |       285.6 ns | 3,515,349.8 |  1.00 |    0.1922 |         - |        - |     1208 B |        1.00 |
|                      ConvertSplitJoin |     1 |       288.2 ns |      0.52 ns |      0.49 ns |      0.13 ns |       287.3 ns |       287.9 ns |       288.0 ns |       288.6 ns |       289.0 ns | 3,470,193.9 |  1.01 |    0.1526 |         - |        - |      960 B |        0.79 |
|                                       |       |                |              |              |              |                |                |                |                |                |             |       |           |           |          |            |             |
|                    ConvertReplaceTrim |    10 |     1,332.6 ns |      2.31 ns |      2.05 ns |      0.55 ns |     1,330.4 ns |     1,331.2 ns |     1,332.0 ns |     1,333.8 ns |     1,336.6 ns |   750,429.1 |  0.51 |    0.9518 |         - |        - |     5976 B |        0.54 |
|                   ConvertStateMachine |    10 |     1,475.3 ns |      6.26 ns |      5.85 ns |      1.51 ns |     1,466.1 ns |     1,470.9 ns |     1,476.9 ns |     1,480.4 ns |     1,483.3 ns |   677,806.8 |  0.57 |    0.4845 |         - |        - |     3040 B |        0.27 |
| ConvertStateMachineValueStringBuilder |    10 |     1,700.1 ns |      3.87 ns |      3.62 ns |      0.93 ns |     1,695.5 ns |     1,697.1 ns |     1,699.9 ns |     1,702.1 ns |     1,707.4 ns |   588,199.9 |  0.66 |    0.2308 |         - |        - |     1448 B |        0.13 |
|                      ConvertSplitJoin |    10 |     2,390.6 ns |      6.72 ns |      5.95 ns |      1.59 ns |     2,375.1 ns |     2,387.7 ns |     2,391.2 ns |     2,394.7 ns |     2,397.0 ns |   418,308.3 |  0.92 |    1.2741 |    0.0076 |        - |     8016 B |        0.72 |
|                    ConvertStringSplit |    10 |     2,592.7 ns |      7.13 ns |      6.67 ns |      1.72 ns |     2,577.7 ns |     2,589.3 ns |     2,594.1 ns |     2,596.8 ns |     2,603.4 ns |   385,704.6 |  1.00 |    1.7738 |    0.0191 |        - |    11128 B |        1.00 |
|                                       |       |                |              |              |              |                |                |                |                |                |             |       |           |           |          |            |             |
|                    ConvertReplaceTrim |   100 |    12,518.4 ns |     21.15 ns |     18.75 ns |      5.01 ns |    12,481.1 ns |    12,504.8 ns |    12,522.9 ns |    12,529.9 ns |    12,551.6 ns |    79,882.5 |  0.50 |    9.3231 |         - |        - |    58528 B |        0.53 |
|                   ConvertStateMachine |   100 |    14,323.0 ns |     79.79 ns |     66.63 ns |     18.48 ns |    14,241.6 ns |    14,259.6 ns |    14,310.5 ns |    14,377.4 ns |    14,421.3 ns |    69,817.7 |  0.57 |    4.6844 |         - |        - |    29496 B |        0.27 |
| ConvertStateMachineValueStringBuilder |   100 |    16,860.2 ns |     83.67 ns |     78.27 ns |     20.21 ns |    16,744.6 ns |    16,791.9 ns |    16,862.8 ns |    16,909.2 ns |    17,007.0 ns |    59,311.4 |  0.67 |    2.2583 |         - |        - |    14224 B |        0.13 |
|                      ConvertSplitJoin |   100 |    23,391.0 ns |     62.49 ns |     52.18 ns |     14.47 ns |    23,310.6 ns |    23,356.4 ns |    23,373.8 ns |    23,420.0 ns |    23,501.9 ns |    42,751.4 |  0.93 |   12.4817 |    0.3662 |        - |    78576 B |        0.71 |
|                    ConvertStringSplit |   100 |    25,065.7 ns |     52.48 ns |     49.09 ns |     12.67 ns |    24,993.3 ns |    25,031.0 ns |    25,061.3 ns |    25,093.8 ns |    25,154.8 ns |    39,895.2 |  1.00 |   17.5171 |    0.9155 |        - |   110312 B |        1.00 |
|                                       |       |                |              |              |              |                |                |                |                |                |             |       |           |           |          |            |             |
|                    ConvertReplaceTrim |  1000 |   147,715.0 ns |    608.00 ns |    538.97 ns |    144.05 ns |   146,797.0 ns |   147,418.1 ns |   147,726.7 ns |   148,141.3 ns |   148,468.5 ns |     6,769.8 |  0.46 |  181.6406 |  181.6406 | 181.6406 |   584311 B |        0.53 |
|                   ConvertStateMachine |  1000 |   163,280.4 ns |    919.44 ns |    860.04 ns |    222.06 ns |   161,186.8 ns |   163,052.3 ns |   163,518.7 ns |   163,916.4 ns |   164,141.1 ns |     6,124.4 |  0.51 |   90.8203 |   90.8203 |  90.8203 |   294157 B |        0.27 |
| ConvertStateMachineValueStringBuilder |  1000 |   177,384.7 ns |    844.07 ns |    704.84 ns |    195.49 ns |   176,157.2 ns |   176,992.2 ns |   177,428.4 ns |   177,866.1 ns |   178,703.1 ns |     5,637.5 |  0.56 |   43.4570 |   43.4570 |  43.4570 |   142053 B |        0.13 |
|                      ConvertSplitJoin |  1000 |   284,302.9 ns |  1,357.49 ns |  1,269.79 ns |    327.86 ns |   282,811.5 ns |   283,233.0 ns |   283,728.3 ns |   285,461.1 ns |   286,630.2 ns |     3,517.4 |  0.89 |   95.2148 |   95.2148 |  95.2148 |   784273 B |        0.71 |
|                    ConvertStringSplit |  1000 |   319,248.8 ns |  1,020.42 ns |    954.50 ns |    246.45 ns |   318,119.0 ns |   318,578.5 ns |   318,849.0 ns |   320,045.8 ns |   321,017.6 ns |     3,132.4 |  1.00 |  136.2305 |  136.2305 | 136.2305 |  1102250 B |        1.00 |
|                                       |       |                |              |              |              |                |                |                |                |                |             |       |           |           |          |            |             |
|                    ConvertReplaceTrim | 10000 | 1,511,118.7 ns | 12,495.43 ns | 11,688.23 ns |  3,017.89 ns | 1,493,798.9 ns | 1,502,385.7 ns | 1,513,565.7 ns | 1,518,538.1 ns | 1,532,550.5 ns |       661.8 |  0.22 |  980.4688 |  978.5156 | 978.5156 |  5841093 B |        0.53 |
|                   ConvertStateMachine | 10000 | 1,511,180.1 ns |  4,264.31 ns |  3,988.83 ns |  1,029.91 ns | 1,506,177.4 ns | 1,507,441.9 ns | 1,511,762.0 ns | 1,512,933.6 ns | 1,518,652.7 ns |       661.7 |  0.22 |  496.0938 |  496.0938 | 496.0938 |  2940451 B |        0.27 |
| ConvertStateMachineValueStringBuilder | 10000 | 1,730,956.3 ns |  4,569.84 ns |  4,051.05 ns |  1,082.69 ns | 1,723,748.0 ns | 1,729,037.7 ns | 1,731,763.8 ns | 1,733,297.9 ns | 1,736,869.7 ns |       577.7 |  0.26 |  246.0938 |  246.0938 | 246.0938 |  1420185 B |        0.13 |
|                      ConvertSplitJoin | 10000 | 3,259,779.3 ns |  7,764.95 ns |  6,062.36 ns |  1,750.05 ns | 3,251,508.5 ns | 3,254,920.0 ns | 3,259,697.4 ns | 3,262,705.4 ns | 3,272,817.5 ns |       306.8 |  0.48 |  988.2813 |  781.2500 | 390.6250 |  7840602 B |        0.71 |
|                    ConvertStringSplit | 10000 | 6,777,254.8 ns | 48,469.96 ns | 45,338.83 ns | 11,706.44 ns | 6,704,766.6 ns | 6,732,650.9 ns | 6,781,015.6 ns | 6,813,608.9 ns | 6,849,229.2 ns |       147.6 |  1.00 | 1992.1875 | 1945.3125 | 992.1875 | 11021142 B |        1.00 |
```

Comment: I've dumped the full code file at https://pastebin.com/Tf3nyH1x if anyone wants to play around with it.

Comment: I realised that outputting to char[] would also remove the overhead of .Append() calls much more easily than batching entire numbers, so I gave it a try. It gave me:
 1121 ms / 2313272 ticks, 22.42ms / 46265.44ticks per conversion

Comment: nice job.. i think you missed that Łukasz's  answer yields wrong output. i played with this a little more after my answer because it seemed to me it should be simpler than all the answers given (including mine) and more efficient.  i ran a comparison on the solutions (before i saw yours) and my second method was always faster. but i noticed there are 2 assumptions made which might not always be true. the data will never have leading 0 and the ",0" will always be a 0. those assumptions may or may not be true. only the OP might know.

Comment: i ran them all in 100k iterations (including some safe versions i made per the assumptions i mentioned before) and your method is faster than all my safe methods, but slower than my second "unsafe" (the ones provided as solutions). these are the numbers i have for 100k iterations (in milliseconds) using the string provided:
MyReplace2 431.62730000000005
ConvertStateMachine 531.77960000000007
OliverLoop 533.7842
MyReplace1 604.8893
MyOptimizedAttempt2 686.008
ElgasparForeach 1021.5018

very nice job on efficiency.. i see your point on "depends on efficiency requirements". i give +1

Comment: i think your extended version of the test data shouldve probably used appendline, rather than just append. seems thats the format the data is in.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine. Maybe you could write it a bit more elegant like this:

```
string[] coordinatesVal = coordinateTxt.Trim().Split(new string[] { ",0" }, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (string line in coordinatesVal)
{
    string[] numbers = line.Trim().Split(',');
    result += numbers[0] + " " + numbers[1] + ", ";
}
result = result.Remove(result.Count()-2, 2);
```

Note the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter of `Split` method so you don't have to deal with empty lines into *foreach* block.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do extremely short one-liner. Harder to debug, but in simple cases does the work.

```
string result =
  string.Join(", ",
    coordinateTxt.Trim().Split(new string[] { ",0" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
      Select(i => i.Replace(",", " ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

heres another way without *defining your own loops* and replace methods, or using LINQ.

```
 string coordinateTxt = @" -82.9494547,36.2913021,0
 -83.0784938,36.2347521,0
 -82.9537782,36.079235,0";

            string[] coordinatesVal = coordinateTxt.Replace(",", "*").Trim().Split(new string[] { "*0", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string result = string.Join(",", coordinatesVal).Replace("*", " ");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or even

```
            string coordinateTxt = @" -82.9494540,36.2913021,0
-83.0784938,36.2347521,0
-82.9537782,36.079235,0";

            string result = coordinateTxt.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace($",", " ").Replace(" 0", ", ").Trim(new char[]{ ',',' ' });
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Are you sure `.Replace` and `.Join` works without loops ;)

Comment: explicit loops in code. using the built in .net methods without writing your own loops.

Comment: @Fabio i clarified the heading for you. since it was not clear for you what i meant.